# ASP.NET MVC - Cache Sliding expiration works in local but not working in server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

Does somebody here experienced this type of problem? I have an application where in on starting of the page, when user logs in, his/her data will be cached by Cache object and set it to expire when inactive for 15 hours. at my local, the application is working as expected. But when I transferred it to server, it works some time and when I leave it with not less than the time I set on sliding expiration, the Cache object goes null. What could seems to be the cause of it? Is there something that I need to modify in the application to make sliding expiration of Cache work as expected? below is the image of error I encountered.

[image]

Comment: Sliding expiration means the cache expiration time will move further if the cache is accessed. If you do not access the cache then it should expire after the specified inactive period. Also if the application pool becomes idle the cache will be cleared and memory will be released to other services.

Comment: does it mean that the cause of cache object being null is because of the application pool becoming idle and clearing the cache object of application?

Comment: Possibly. An useful strategy is to check if cache object is null before accessing it. If it is null then re-load the cache object for further requests. By the way storing user specific information in a cache is a bad idea unless there are only a few users for your application.

Comment: my bad I did it like that way :( I just done it because I thought of this being alternative for sessions.

Comment: But, is it still going to be cleared when the app pool recycles while cache object is accessing by user?

Comment: Yes, cache will be cleared if app pool is recycled. If you are building an website you can use session cookies (encrypted) to store user data. Also in asp.net identity you can add claims to user identity and access them later.